# Azure Functions - Table Storage Trigger with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need a way to trigger the Azure functions when an entity is added to the Azure Table storage. Is there a way to do this ? When I tried to add a new Azure function, I did not see any Azure Table storage trigger. I see there is Queue and Blob triggers available.

If there is no support for the Azure table storage trigger, then should I need to have a Http trigger and have the Azure Table storage as input binding ?

Thanks

Comment: hi Venki, could you please share code? I have the same problem. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no trigger binding for Table Storage.

Here's a detailed view on what is supported by the different bindings available today:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#overview

> If there is no support for the Azure table storage trigger, then should I need to have a Http trigger and have the Azure Table storage as input binding ?

Yes, this approach would work and would allow you to pass the table data as an input while relying on a separate trigger. Depending on the type of clients you are working with, and your requirements, using a queue trigger is also another good option.

Comment: hi Fabio, could you please share code? I have the same problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

@venki What the Fabio Cavalcante said to you is really true. Azure Function doesn't have a trigger option for Storage Table. But, whether your business needs store the data into the Storage Table and you as a Developer decide to use Azure Function into your architecture, you're able to configure you Function to use data that will come from Storage Table as a Input to your Function! This works really well.

But, There is another way to configure your Function to have "automagically" trigger, using Storage Queue (for small business) or Service Bus (for a business that needs a mechanism more robust)

Comment: hi Jose, could you please share code for ServiceBus? I have the same problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that Azure Functions have a trigger now for Azure Storage Tables:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table